# Unable to push GCM notification using node-gcm

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to push GCM from node, I am using node-gcm, but I am getting ENOTFOUND error

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var gcmMessage = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'notify',
    delayWhileIdle: false,
    timeToLive: 3600,
    data: {
       title: "Hai",
       message: "Message",
    }
});
var gcmIds = ['<myid>'];

var sender = new gcm.Sender('<mysender id>',{'proxy':'<proxyip>:8080'});
sender.send(gcmMessage, gcmIds, 4, function(err, ret){
    console.log('>>> sendGcm: ', err, ret);
});
```

I am getting error

```
sendGcm:  { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddr
info ENOTFOUND] code: 'ECONNRESET' } null
```

Comment: Issue with proxy. How do you set up/request proxy?

Comment: The request proxy is currently controlled by the organisation, but I think GCM is not blocked, because **curl** command definitely works.

Comment: Maybe the proxy needs credentials which is often the case for https protocol AFAIK. Try this: `'<mysender id>',{'proxy':'http://user:password@<proxyip>:8080'`

Comment: No, the proxy is not programmed with any username or password, a php/perl/java version of GCM definitely works in my machine

Comment: Does this help?: https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/pull/115